# Redraw drawn line on mapview

Tags: android, line, coordinates, android-mapview

Developing an Android app to draw more than four lines and connect them each to appear that as polygon. Using the angle I find coordinates where to start and end the line, then I draw on mapview. But my need is to, the polygon starts the first line from base(which is horizontal to the device). How to reposition the line? Help me to find a solution..

The image shows my real need..

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rbgoix&s=8#.U8S6NZSSy80

Code:

```
 m=0;
 x[m]= (dis[m]*1000)*Math.sin((angle1[m])*Math.PI / 180);
 y[m]= (dis[m]*1000)*Math.cos((angle1[m])*Math.PI / 180);
 GeoPoint g = new GeoPoint((int)(x[m]),(int)(y[m]));
 Point p=new Point();
 projection.toPixels(g, p);
 Path path=new Path();
    l=pp.x;
    o=pp.y;

for( m=1;m<j+1;m++)  
{   
 x[m]= (dis[m]*1000)*Math.sin((angle1[m])*Math.PI / 180);
 y[m]= (dis[m]*1000)*Math.cos((angle1[m])*Math.PI / 180);
 GeoPoint g1 = new GeoPoint((int)(x[m]),(int)(y[m]));
 Point p1=new Point();
 projection.toPixels(g1, p1);
 Path path1=new Path(); 
if(m!=j)
 {
 path1.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
 path1.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
 canvas.drawPath(path1, mPaint);
    lPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath((sf.format(distance[m-1])).toString()+" ,"+m+" ,"+v[m], path1,10 ,20, lPaint);
}
else
{
p1.x=l;
p1.y=o;
path1.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
path1.lineTo(pp.x, pp.y);
canvas.drawPath(path1, mPaint);
    lPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath((sf.format(distance[m-1])).toString()+" ,"+m, path1,10 ,20, lPaint);
}
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Angle"+distance[m], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    p.x=p1.x;
    p.y=p1.y;
```

}

Comment: what you have tried post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code -

```
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 
                    // Here add your latitude & longitude of locations
                    /*double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); */
                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(5);
                lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);  

            }
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but it only draws line. Don't draw first line on base. Did u see the image i uploaded? That is my need sir.

Comment: yes.but i'm not getting what exactly Don't draw first line on base. is?

Comment: In your case i think first you have to get 2 locations which are same like same on x axis.drawing line only take latitude & longitude of locations.you have to decide which locations in which sequence you have to pass for drawing line

Comment: My first coordinate is in angle of 350 degree second is in 280 degree and so on. I need the first line as, for eg: 0 degree to 180 degree it must parallel to device na that's what i need. Again for the 3rd and further points angle must remain same(inner polygon's angle)

Comment: It's not possible.if you do this kind of things,your location(latitude & longitude) obviously going to change

Comment: I'm using mapview v1. Another way to straight the first line is rotating the 1st point to some angle 220 degree clockwise, then it looks straight right? How to find that angle and how to apply to other all lines to remain the inner angle same..

Comment: refer this -https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows?hl=it

Comment: Ya. Fix the 1st 2 points in 0 and 180 degree then, can I fix remaining all points to above 180 to 360 degree(converting lower points to appear on above 180 to 360 degree)

Comment: I already reffered that link sir. Can I draw a line with some angle from end of another line related to the drawn line. Like manually using the protracter